# hide the extra spacing taken by visibility:hidden

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

hello i want to hide the extra spacing taken by `visibility:hidden`. In the code when i select `sort by date` then it is replaced by default content, but when select `sort by topic` it comes under sort by date output. But i don't want this. I want to replace o/p of `sort of topic` to `sort by date`. I think it comes because of using `visibility:hidden`. Can anyone suggest me how i remove that space. I used `display:none` too, but no use.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onloadfun()
{
  document.getElementById("hideall").style.visibility="hidden";
}
function optionCheck()
{
    if( document.getElementById("sorting").value=="bydate")
    {
        document.getElementById("topic1").style.visibility ="visible";
        document.getElementById("topic").style.visibility ="hidden";
        document.getElementById("showByDefault").style.display ="none";
    }
    if( document.getElementById("sorting").value =="bytopic")
    {
        document.getElementById("topic1").style.visibility ="hidden";
        document.getElementById("topic").style.visibility ="visible";
        document.getElementById("showByDefault").style.display ="none";
    }
// validation of dropdownlist
    var x = document.getElementById("sorting");
    var option = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    var strUser1 = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
    if(option=="s")
    {
        document.form.options.focus();
        return false;
    }
return true;    
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onloadfun()">
<form name="form">
<select id="sorting" style="width:140px" onChange="optionCheck()">
  <option id="s">---Sort By----</option>
  <option value="bydate">Sort By Date</option>
  <option value="bytopic">Sort By Topic</option>  
</select>
</form>
<br /><br /><hr /><br /><br />

<?php   include 'connection.php';  ?>
<div id="showByDefault">
<?php
  echo "default content";   
?>
</div>
<div id="hideall">
    <div id="topic1">
      <?php echo "hideing 1"; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="topic">
      <?php echo "hideing 2"; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please remove the <br> tag and then try

Comment: removing <br> inn't work. Removing <br> is not correct way to replace sort by topic content.

Comment: What does the markup provided by PHP look like? Can you give a simple example? Any CSS?

Comment: sorry but i didn't get you. am not using any css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follows.
I preferred to use **display:block and display:none** instead set visiblity
and also recommend **jquery** $(selector).show() and $(selector).hide() method.

```
        <html>
<head>
    <script>
        function onloadfun() {
            document.getElementById("hideall").style.display = "none";
        }

        function optionCheck() {
            if (document.getElementById("sorting").value == "bydate") {
                document.getElementById("hideall").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("topic1").style.display = "block";

                document.getElementById("topic").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("showByDefault").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("sorting").value == "bytopic") {

                document.getElementById("hideall").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("topic1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("topic").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("showByDefault").style.display = "none";
            }
            // validation of dropdownlist
            var x = document.getElementById("sorting");
            var option = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
            var strUser1 = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
            if (option == "s") {
                document.form.options.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onloadfun()">
    <form name="form">
        <select id="sorting" style="width:140px" onChange="optionCheck()">
            <option id="s">---Sort By----</option>
            <option value="bydate">Sort By Date</option>
            <option value="bytopic">Sort By Topic</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
    <br />

    <?php //include 'connection.php'; ?>
    <div id="showByDefault">
        <?php echo "default content"; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="hideall">
        <div id="topic1">
            <?php echo "hideing 1"; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="topic">
            <?php echo "hideing 2"; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Try changing above three function in your code.

Comment: have you changed three function that i provided above. it's working i have tested on my local machine.

Comment: added complete code. let me know still it's not working

Comment: in code i don't know why  add    document.getElementById("hideall").style.display = "block"; in both if statement??? Can you plz tell me

Comment: i have seen in your code you don't want to display "hideall" div when loads first time so onload you have hide and we need to show while on change. you can remove all three if you want

Answer (score 2):

Some reading:

[`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

> The visibility CSS property has two purposes:
>
> 1. The hidden value hides an element but leaves space where it would
>      have been. The collapse value hides rows or columns of a table. It
> 2. also collapses XUL elements

[`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

> In addition to the many different display box types, the value none
>   lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none, all
>   descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document
>   is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tre

An example based on your code but using `display` and setting it by a `class` using [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

```js
var sorting = document.getElementById('sorting'),
    showByDefault = document.getElementById('showByDefault'),
    topic = document.getElementById('topic'),
    topic1 = document.getElementById('topic1');

sorting.addEventListener('change', function optionCheck(e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if (target.value === 's') {
        console.log('Do something here.');
    } else if (target.value === 'bydate') {
        topic1.classList.remove('hide');
        topic.classList.add('hide');
        showByDefault.classList.add('hide');
    } else if (target.value === 'bytopic') {
        topic1.classList.add('hide');
        topic.classList.remove('hide');
        showByDefault.classList.add('hide');
    }
}, false);
```

```css
#sorting {
    width: 140px;
}
hr {
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
    <select id="sorting">
        <option value="s">---Sort By----</option>
        <option value="bydate">Sort By Date</option>
        <option value="bytopic">Sort By Topic</option>
    </select>
</form>
<hr>
<div id="showByDefault">"default content";</div>
<div id="topic1" class="hide">"hiding 1";</div>
<div id="topic" class="hide">"hiding 2";</div>
```

The example is using [`unobtrusive JavaScript`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and unobtrusive CSS.

[The principles of unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: yes this works too. thanks lot. now i got two different solution on my query. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Use **display:none** instead of **visibility hidden**.
See example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: i used too, but still no use. it didn't replace the content.